# Изменение видимости элемента управления при обновлении свойства во ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, события

К примеру, есть класс **User**. Есть *ViewModel*, в которой есть свойство **LastUser**. Свойство периодически обновляется, генерируя **NotifyPropertyChanged**. На форме, поверх остальных элементов, лежит невидимая панель. При обновлении свойства, необходимо показать панель на несколько секунд, а затем спрятать. Как можно реализовать такое поведение? Есть ли какой-нибудь **EventTriger** или **DataTrigger**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наиболее простым видится вынести в VM отдельное свойство для видимости панели
и сделать метод, который запускать в сеттере `LastUser`:

```
private async void ShowDetails()
{
    IsVisiblePanel = true;
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    IsVisiblePanel = false;
}
```

[image: Details]

Если не хотите делать это в VM - можно сделать во View, подписавшись вручную на `PropertyChanged` и делая тоже самое.

---

Другой вариант, немного более замороченый - задействовать анимацию.

Давайте будем действовать через прозрачность, у меня вот такая панель:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0"
            DataContext="{Binding SelectedUser}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat={}Имя: {0}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sex, StringFormat={}Пол: {0}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age, StringFormat={}Возраст: {0}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Phone, StringFormat={}Телефон: {0}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Обратите внимание, у панели установлен `DataContext`, это важно, мы этим воспользуемся в дальнейшем.

Давайте добавим в панель стиль и определим триггер, который будет скрывать панель когда она полностью прозрачна:

```
<Style TargetType="StackPanel">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="0">
            <Trigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger.Setters>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Хорошо, а теперь управлять прозрачностью будет анимация, для этого запустим ее в `EventTrigger`

```
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard AutoReverse="True">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                     From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
```

Чтобы событие `Binding.TargetUpdated` возникало нужно его включить:
`DataContext="{Binding SelectedUser, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"`

Теперь надо отключить панель в обычном режиме: `Opacity="0"`

Ну и можно сделать анимацию посимпатичнее:

```
                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
```

[image: Details2]

Полный код панели, на всякий случай:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0" Opacity="0"
            DataContext="{Binding SelectedUser, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
    <StackPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="0">
                    <Trigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger.Setters>
                </Trigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard AutoReverse="True">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                             From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Style>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat={}Имя: {0}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sex, StringFormat={}Пол: {0}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age, StringFormat={}Возраст: {0}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Phone, StringFormat={}Телефон: {0}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

---

PS: как раз вчера появилась [статья на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/336692/), в которой описаны возможные замены подписке на `Binding.TargetUpdated`.
Получается всё можно сделать гораздо проще используя `PropertyChangedTrigger` из пакета `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions`